# I am uploading the site to hosting in php and mysql, and the site works normally on local hosting, but this malfunction occurred while uploading it

Tags: mysql

[this is the problem  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGb6n.png)

```
<?php

use App\Utils;
include 'path.php';

$firstCollection = isset ($this->collections[0]) ? $this->collections[0] : null;
$secondCollection = isset($this->collections[1]) ? $this->collections[1] : null;
$thirdCollection = isset($this->collections[2]) ? $this->collections[2] : null;
$fourthCollection = isset($this->collections[3]) ? $this->collections[3] : null;


?>
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What error message were you getting ? Are u using any particular framework?

Comment: This is massage error in browser.        Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/u279465613/domains/culinarycreationss.com/public_html/index.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/u279465613/domains/culinarycreationss.com/public_html/index.php on line 6

Comment: Yes, you cannot use '$this' outside a class. It's a special variable used to refer to the current object from within a class.